# Defining citation commands with different case for the same label

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am using LaTeX on Windows and I need to customize the formatting of citation labels in my thesis. I produced a new citation style fitting my needs for the `natbib` package, but I have trouble with label formatting for the `\cite{}` (`\citep{}` etc.) commands. The citation style I use requires the author name to be uppercase when in parentheses, like (KNUTH, 1984, p. 42), but differently when not in parentheses, stated by Knuth (1984, p. 42). As a workaround I type the author name by hand and then I use `\citeyear(Knuth1984)`. Unfortunately, that way only years are clickable, not the author name.

The document structure is rather complicated, I use a .sty file for the thesis typesetting, so I'll provide at least relevant packages I've put into the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[Bc,Barevne]{sci.muni.thesis.uprava}
\begin{document}
Citation in parentheses is great \citep{Knuth1984}.
But we also love citation in text, said \citet{Knuth1984}!
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Desired result should look like this:

Citation in parentheses is great (KNUTH, 1984).

But we also love citation in text, said Knuth (1984)!

Also, the bibliography entry written after `\bibliography{biblio}` should have author last name in upper case with first names shortened to one letter. I managed to do that, but I think you should know for clarification. The bibliography entry:

KNUTH, D. 1984. The TeX book ...

The .bib file is formatted like so:

```
@book{Knuth1984,
    author = "Donald Knuth",
    title = "The \TeX book",
    ...
}
```

I can provide by .bst file, but I don't think that's necessary. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably the `,bst` is not necessary, but a minimal example of a document is.

Comment: Edited. Also, everything works just fine, I'm just curious if it's possible to achieve desired results.

Comment: I guess that when you have two authors, you want “AUTHORONE and AUTHORTWO” in a parenthetical citation, with lowercase “and”. For this some changes to the `.bst` file are necessary. Maybe you already have something on this line. Can you add what you get in the `.bbl` file for a two author paper (and maybe also for three or more)? If you instead want “AUTHORONE AND AUTHORTWO” for two authors and “AUTHOR ET AL.” for more than two, I think I have a solution.

Comment: That could probably best be done changing the definition of `bbl.and` and other related functions inside the `.bst` file, but keeping the AUTHORONE and AUTHORTWO or AUTHORONE et al. behaviour is intended in my case. What I aim for is the possibility to produce citations with uppercase author name for one command and capitalized for another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both macros `\citep` and `\citet` internally use `\NAT@citetp`, but when the first is used, `\ifNAT@swa` is set to true, whereas the second sets it to false. Then it's just a matter of changing the definition of `\NAT@nmfmt` so that it uses `\MakeUppercase` in the case of `\citep`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Knuth1984,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  title = {The {\TeX}book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = 1984,    
}
@book{multi,
  author = {A. Uthor and W. Riter},
  title = {A book},
  publisher = {Some},
  year = 1984,    
}
@book{multi2,
  author = {A. Uthor and W. Riter and S. C. I. Entist},
  title = {Another book},
  publisher = {Some},
  year = 1984,    
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\NAT@nmfmt}[1]{%
  \ifNAT@swa\expandafter\MakeUppercase\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi{{\NAT@up #1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Citation in parentheses is great \citep{Knuth1984}.
But we also love citation in text, said \citet{Knuth1984}!

Let's see multiauthor: \citep{multi} or \citet{multi}.

Let's see multiauthor: \citep{multi2} or \citet{multi2}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This also capitalizes “AND” and “ET AL.”. If this is not desired, the `.bst` file must be changed so that it outputs something like

```
\begin{thebibliography}{3}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi

\bibitem[Knuth(1984)]{Knuth1984}
Donald~E. Knuth.
\newblock \emph{The {\TeX}book}.
\newblock Addison-Wesley, 1984.

\bibitem[Uthor \NATand{} Riter(1984)]{multi}
A.~Uthor and W.~Riter.
\newblock \emph{A book}.
\newblock Some, 1984.

\bibitem[Uthor \NATetal{}(1984)Uthor, Riter, and Entist]{multi2}
A.~Uthor, W.~Riter, and S.~C.~I. Entist.
\newblock \emph{Another book}.
\newblock Some, 1984.

\end{thebibliography}
```

with `\NATand{}` and `\NATetal{}` instead of the hardwired `and` and `et al.`. The LaTeX code above should be supplemented by

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATand}{and}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\NATetal}{et~al.}
```

Comment: Redefining the `\NAT@nmfmt` worked great! I'll probably try tinkering with "and" and "et al." as you mentioned, but it is not critical and the citations are basically 99 % the way I wanted them. So thank you very much, you were very helpful.